# Spring Boot: Embedded servlet container is not working properly

Tags: spring-boot, eclipse-emf, emf, eclipse-emf-ecore, mdht

My project is using MDHT(Model Driven Health Tools) Runtime Api Library which is based on Eclipse Modeling Framework(EMF). It works when servers in Spring MVC project. But for some reason the EMF package registry is not getting loaded properly and therefore it cannot deserialize as a Consol CCD document when try to servers in Sprint Boot project.

Code Sample:

```
Mu2consolPackage.eINSTANCE.unload();
ConsolPackage.eINSTANCE.eClass();
CDAUtil.load(in, result);
```

Link:

1. MDHT(https://github.com/mdht/mdht-models)
2. User Documentation (https://www.projects.openhealthtools.org/sf/wiki/do/viewPage/projects.mdht/wiki/User%20Documentation)

**Edit:**

After changing to use external tomcat to deploy instead of spring boot embedded servlet container. It works, but still cannot resolve using embedded container.

Comment: Is it your ticket? https://github.com/mdht/mdht-models/issues/111